# IE9 Commerical site logo placement

Tags: internet-explorer-9, favicon

In the IE9 Commerical Marvel, Twitter & Pandora seem to "take over" the browser. Is this actually possible, and if so, how? here is a link to an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlxaH.jpg

I assume it has something to do with the favicon.

Answer (score 1):

The sites have been [**pinned**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh535226.aspx) (requires IE9 and Windows7), which adds the favicon outside of the URL box.